# Convolution of two random variables with common pdf of $e^{-t}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with common pdf where
>   $f_X(t) = f_Y (t) = 
> e^{−t}$
>   for $t > 0$,
>   and $0$ otherwise.
>   Find the density function of $2X + Y$.

I attempted the following convolution:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(t-y)f_Y(y)dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{t}f_X(2x)f_Y(y)dy$$

$$e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}f_X(t-y)dy$$

Now I can substitute  $f_X(u)$ for $f_X(t-y)$ by converting the bounds of the integral, and since $t-0=t$ and $t-t=0$ and $du=-dy$ and I have

$$-e^{-t}\int_{t}^{0}f_X(u)du$$

$$-e^{-2t}\int_{t}^{0}du$$

This is obviously incorrect and I am sure there must be more than one mistake, I am just not sure what they are.

Comment: First, find the density of $f_{2X}$, then do the convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z=2X$, then
$$F_{Z}(z)=\Pr[Z\le z]=\Pr[2X\le z]=\Pr[X\le \tfrac z2]=F_X(\tfrac z2)$$
Differentiating:
$f_Z(z)=\frac12f_X(\tfrac z2)$.

The pdf of $T=Z+Y$ is therefore given by:

$$\begin{align}
f_T(t)&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_Z(\tau)f_Y(t-\tau)d\tau\\[8pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\tfrac12f_X(\tfrac{\tau}2)f_Y(t-\tau)d\tau\\[8pt]
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\tau/2}e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau\tag{t>0}\\[8pt]
&=\frac12e^{-t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\tau/2}d\tau\tag{t>0}\\[8pt]
&=\frac12e^{-t}\,\cdot\,2(e^{t/2} - 1)\tag{t>0}
\end{align}$$
and $f_T(t)=0, \forall t\le 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is when you say $f_X(2x) = e^{-2x}$. Normally the way you do it is as follows:
$$F_{2X}(x) = Pr(2X <x ) = Pr(X < \frac{x}{2}) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{2}} f_X(t) \ dt $$
Take a change of variable of $u = 2t$ you get
$$F_{2X}(x) =\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(\frac{u}{2}) \frac{1}{2} du = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(\frac{u}{2}) du$$
The PDF is the derivative of the CDF, i.e.
$$f_{2X}(x) = F_{2X}'(x) = \frac{1}{2}f_X(\frac{u}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \qquad x>0$$
Now, you can convolve $f_{2X}(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$ with $f_Y(y) = e^{-y}$, as you were doing.